# quantum results in Undefined applications: [stdlib,kernel]

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I try to use [quantum](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir) as a cronjob tool for a Phoenix application. It works with out a problem on my development system. But I can't get it running in production. `./node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch b -p && MIX_ENV=prod mix do phoenix.digest, release --env=prod --upgrade` always ends up with this error:

```
Generated abc app
==> Assembling release..
==> Building release abc:1.2.53 using environment prod
==> Including ERTS 8.2 from /usr/lib/erlang/erts-8.2
==> Failed to build release:

    Undefined applications: [stdlib,kernel]
```

- Development: macOS 10.12.2. Erlang 19. Elixir 1.4.0
- Production: Debian Linux. Erlang 19. Elixir 1.4.0

I'm building production on the target and development on the development machine. When I delete the quantum parts in `mix.exs` it works.

The setup:

**mix.exs**

```
def application do
  [mod: {Abc, []},
   applications: [:phoenix,
                  :phoenix_pubsub,
                  :phoenix_html,
                  :cowboy,
                  :logger,
                  :gettext,
                  :phoenix_ecto,
                  :ex_machina,
                  :phoenix_html_simplified_helpers,
                  :bamboo,
                  :bamboo_smtp,
                  :mariaex,
                  :httpoison,
                  :slugger,
                  :timex_ecto,
                  :word_smith,
                  :arc,
                  :arc_ecto,
                  :quantum]]
end

defp deps do
  [{:ecto, "~> 2.0.1", override: true},
   {:bamboo, "~> 0.6"},
   {:bamboo_smtp, "~> 1.1.0"},
   {:phoenix, "~> 1.2.0"},
   {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0.0-rc"},
   {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.8"},
   {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
   {:gettext, "~> 0.12.1"},
   [...]
   {:distillery, "~> 0.10"},
   {:quantum, ">= 1.8.1"}]
end
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What erlang version do you have locally and remotely?

Comment: 19 on dev and production.

Comment: One can not build releases on the arch, that differs from target: “[The build host must be similar to the production/staging hosts.](https://github.com/boldpoker/edeliver/#installation)”—you probably need to reconsider deploy strategy.

Comment: I'm building on the target. So that can't be it.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with the quantum package?

Comment: If I remove quantum from mix.exs it works.

Comment: Can you try distillery 1.1.0? Looks like a similar bug was fixed in 1.1.0: https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/commit/3f721e849be5cb83914b78406db827ee81e3e4e9.

Comment: Bingo! Upgrading distillery solved the problem. I would have never thought about this possibility. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading [distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery) to 1.1.0 solves the problem.

**mix.exs**

```
{:distillery, "~> 1.1.0"}
```